# Laravel / MySQL query raw

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Not sure on how to query this, but let's say I've got two tables as such

Table 1

```
| id         | userid      | points       |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |      1      |     30     
| 2          |      3      |     40    
| 3          |      1      |     30     
| 4          |      3      |     40      
| 5          |      1      |     30    
| 6          |      3      |     40
```

Table 2

```
| id         | userid      | productid    |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |      1      |     4     
| 2          |      3      |     4    
| 3          |      1      |     3     
| 4          |      3      |     3      
| 5          |      1      |     3    
| 6          |      3      |     3
```

I need to get all rows with s from table 1 where points are above 30 and where table2 has a productid of 4

At the moment I have a raw query like this:

```
SELECT userid, SUM(points) as points FROM table1 GROUP BY userid HAVING SUM(points) >= 30 ORDER BY SUM(points) DESC, userid
```

Through DB::select

How can I make sure that all of the results only have a product id of 4 via table2 connected via the userid? Is this where join is applicable and then I see leftjoin and others so I'm not too sure how to go about this, any suggestions appreciated.

EDIT:

I just got this working:

```
SELECT userid, SUM(points) as points FROM table1 LEFTJOIN table2 on table1.userid = table2.userid WHERE table2.productid = '4' GROUP BY userid HAVING SUM(points) >= 30 ORDER BY SUM(points) DESC, userid
```

It is giving me back to correct results, but not 100%sure on join/leftjoin, any feedback if that is OK?

Comment: The query you have added works ?

Comment: Yes but it is not looking for table 2 where productid is 4, as the question. I've found a solution and am about to edit it and answer below comment, not sure if it is the correct way though so any feedback would be appreciated in a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use inner join you get only the related  row that match between productid =4  and sum only this

```
SELECT userid, SUM(points) as points 
FROM table1 
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.userid and productid=4
GROUP BY userid 
HAVING SUM(points) >= 30 
RDER BY SUM(points) DESC, userid
```

or if you are looking for the user that have  on of the product = 4  then you can use

```
SELECT userid, SUM(points) as points 
FROM table1 
inner join (
  select distinct userid 
  from table2 where productid =4

) t on table1.id = t.userid 
GROUP BY userid 
HAVING SUM(points) >= 30 
RDER BY SUM(points) DESC, userid
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually got something working now which is this: SELECT userid, SUM(points) as points FROM table1 LEFTJOIN table2 on table1.userid = table2.userid WHERE table2.productid = '4' GROUP BY userid HAVING SUM(points) >= 30 ORDER BY SUM(points) DESC, userid 

would this be correct or is leftjoin not right here? It does give back the correct rows in my current instance it seems

Comment: explain better  .. my suggestion are right? are wrong?   work ? don'twork?  is what you are looking for?

Comment: Apologies commented too quickly, I also edited original post with a solution that seems to be working, but you're suggesting innerjoin as opposed to the leftjoin I got it working with. Any feedback?

Comment: the use of left join is for rows that don't match in select table using left joi you are calculateing the sum of all the point not only of those with producto = 4  or for user with product = 4  .. If you need only point for row whit product = 4 you should use INNER JOIN as i suggested in my answer ...hope my comment is clear

Comment: Thanks scaisedge, I think that makes sense. I have selected your answer as the solution. Both inner join and left join seems to give me the same result with my small table, but if I understand correctly with INNER JOIN it will only sum points for rows in table2 that have productid is 4